# Extract output from DockerFIle RUN instruction into a LABEL instruction

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build

I want to store more data about my DockerImage in the docker labels for the image.
Namely I want to store the python requirements that are installed in the image into the labels'. The high level of what I want to achieve:

```
FROM xxxx:latest
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
LABEL python_requirements=$(RUN echo $(pip freeze))
```

However, naturally I can't use LABEL and RUN within the same. Is there a common way to get around this? An alternative would be that I built the virtual environment outside of the docker image and push in the pinned list of requirements there, however, would prefer if I can do everything inside the image itself.

Thanks!

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to set the LABEL, ENV, and other values from the output of a RUN step in the Dockerfile.

You can configure the label using build args:

```
FROM xxxx:latest
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
ARG python_requirements
LABEL python_requirements=$python_requirements
```

And then build with a command like:

```bash
docker build --build-arg "python_requirements=$(pip freeze)" ...
```

You can skip the build arg and label in the Dockerfile and add it directly during the build:

```bash
docker build --label "python_requirements=$(pip freeze)" ...
```

You could also modify the image after it has been built. This will change the digest of the image. Examples of tools that do that include Google's `crane mutate` and my own `regctl image mod`.

Comment: Thanks, confirms my suspicions that it's just not possible.